# Detecting refreshing of RefreshScope beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

It is my understanding that when you use Spring Cloud's `RefreshScope` annotation, a Proxy to the data is injected, and the proxy is automatically updated if the backing information is changed. Unfortunately, I need to find a way to be alerted when that refresh occurs, so that my code can re-read the data from the refresh-scoped bean.

Simple example: A scheduled task whose schedule is stored in Cloud Config. Unless you wait until the next execution of the task (which could take a while) or regularly poll the configuration (which seems wasteful), there's no way to know if the configuration has changed.

Comment: Hope using refreshevent would have helped you. I use a similar approach as yours. The scheduled task's schedule is in config, this will be auto updated with RefreshEvent. A sample app is given here https://github.com/winster/SpringSchedulerDynamic. This app gracefully loads the scheduledjob with new schedule and previous jobs with old schedule is gracefully completed. Now when I added an opentracing library into the classpath, it breaks again. That means, on refresh, a new scheduled job is created with new schedule and old schedule retains. Do you know what would have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the refresh occurs `EnvironmentChangeEvent` would be raised in your config client, as the documentation states:

> The application will listen for an `EnvironmentChangedEvent` and react
>   to the change in a couple of standard ways (additional
>   `ApplicationListener`s can be added as `@Bean`s by the user in the normal
>   way).

So, you can define your event listener for this event:

```
public class YourEventListener implements ApplicationListener<EnvironmentChangeEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentChangeEvent event) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: EnvironmentChangedEvent is also called on startup which is ruining things for me

Comment: @user2798694 `event.getSource()` will give you the object on which the Event initially occurred. Maybe by inspecting the source you could filter out startup events

Comment: @AliDehghani The Environment change event doesn't have get source.  Only get keys

Comment: @user2798694 The `getSource` method isn't directly declared in the `EnvironmentChangeEvent` class but inherited from `java.util.EventObject`'s `getSource` method.

Comment: @AliDehghani EnvironmentChangeEvent  getSource is always empty

Comment: @user2798694 Shoot! Then I have no idea what to do, sorry. I would post an update for my answer as soon as I come up with a solution

Comment: @user2798694 see my answer, `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` won't be fired on startup

Answer (score 21):

`EnvironmentChangeEvent` is fired when there's a change in `Environment`. In terms of Spring Cloud Config it means it's triggered when `/env` actuator endpoint is called.

`RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` is fired when refresh of `@RefreshScope` beans has been initiated, e.g. `/refresh` actuator endpoint is called.

That means that you need to register `ApplicationListener<RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent>` like that:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @EventListener(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void onRefresh(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
        // Your code goes here...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think an approach can be to annotate with `@RefreshScope` all your bean that have properties externalized by the configuration and annotated within `@Value ( "${your.prop.key}" )` annotation.

These properties are updated when they changed on configuration.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, after the refresh of properties and application context under scope `RefreshScope`, an event `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` is triggered. You can have a listener for this given the understanding that the properties has finished updates (you can be sure to capture updated values only).